# How to strip date from datetime in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Data looks like this:

```
     Id           Timestamp         Data    Group_Id    
0   5999    2018-01-01 00:00:05.523 125.5   101 
1   6000    2018-01-01 00:00:05.757 125.0   101 
2   6001    2018-01-02 00:00:13.507 127.0   52  
3   6002    2018-01-02 00:00:13.743 126.5   52  
4   6003    2018-01-03 00:00:15.407 125.5   50
```

Basically I want to check/print out the data on a particular date, say `2018-01-02`. I am aware of `striptime` from `datetime` but not sure what's the best way to do it.

Expected output looks like this:

```
     Id           Timestamp         Data    Group_Id    
2   6001    2018-01-02 00:00:13.507 127.0   52  
3   6002    2018-01-02 00:00:13.743 126.5   52
```

I have 2 extended questions:

1) How can we count how many rows in that `2018-01-02` subset?

2) Can we add the second condition on `Group_Id` to filter rows with `Group_Id` equals to 52 on date `2018-01-02`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `dt.strftime` then get all the rows which are equal to your date with `boolean indexing`

```
m = df['Timestamp'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') == '2018-01-02'
df[m]
```

Or in one line:

```
df[df['Timestamp'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d').eq('2018-01-02')]
```

**Output**

```
     Id               Timestamp   Data  Group_Id
2  6001 2018-01-02 00:00:13.507  127.0        52
3  6002 2018-01-02 00:00:13.743  126.5        52
```

---

We can also use `set_index` with `.loc`:

```
df.set_index('Timestamp').loc['2018-01-02'].reset_index()
```

**Output**

```
                Timestamp    Id   Data  Group_Id
0 2018-01-02 00:00:13.507  6001  127.0        52
1 2018-01-02 00:00:13.743  6002  126.5        52
```

---

*note*: if your `Timestamp` column is not `datetime` yet, use this code before running the above:

```
df['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Timestamp'])
```

---

#### Question 1:

```
m = df['Timestamp'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') == '2018-01-02'
df[m].shape[0]
```

Or

```
len(df[m])
```

---

#### Question 2:

```
m1 = df['Timestamp'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') == '2018-01-02'
m2 = df['Group_Id'].eq(52)

df[m1&m2]
```

Comment: Hi @Erfan, thanks for your answer; could you please consider the extended questions added to the original question? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This would give you the expected output:

`df[df.Timestamp.dt.date == pd.to_datetime('2018-01-02')]`

To answer your extended questions, adding `shape[0]` to the end will tell you how many rows are in the subset.

`df[df.Timestamp.dt.date == pd.to_datetime('2018-01-02')].shape[0]`

To add multiple conditions:

`df[(df.Timestamp.dt.date == pd.to_datetime('2018-01-02')) & (df.Group_Id == 52)]`

This is assuming Group_Id is an int, otherwise:

`df[(df.Timestamp.dt.date == pd.to_datetime('2018-01-02')) & (df.Group_Id == '52')]`

Comment: As the other answer stated, make sure your Timestamp column is in datetime format or this will not work.

Comment: Hi @BeRT2me, thanks for your contribution, I will try that:)

Comment: @nilsinelabore I've added to my answer for your extended questions.